# How to specify the Sonar properties file path in VSTS extension for sonar-scanner for MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

sonar server version 6.7.1. I have a C# project and using VSTS MSBUID to build the application.

I am using VSTS extension/plugin for sonar scanner for MSBUILD. In the "Prepare analaysis on SonarQube" task I want to use specify the sonar project properties path in which I have all project settings. How to do it? I tried following

```
sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=../../sonar-project.properties
```

In the logs I get following path

```
INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\Agent3\_work\65\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
```

I don;t know from where .sonarqube\out is coming. My sonar project property file is root folder ("D:\Agent3_work\65\s\sonar-project.properties").

Can anybody please tell me how to specify correctly the path of config file.

Comment: What kind of properties do you want to set other than those you can set in the task?

Comment: I have lot of properties, in config file  

sonar.projectKey=
sonar.projectName=
sonar.analysis.mode=
sonar.projectVersion=
sonar.sources=.
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.exclusions=

sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=
sonar.java.binaries=

sonar.ts.tslintpath=
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=
sonar.buildbreaker.skip=

Comment: MSBuild scanner for C3 code does not support sonar-project.properties, Can use .csproject file instead or if you are using azure pipeline you can configure properties in sonar prepare task